# PHPStorm : List all undefined and unused variables

Tags: undefined, phpstorm

I would like to list all undefined and unused variables in all the files in the project. Is this possible in PHPStorm ?

I am using PHPStorm-7.1 on Mac-Mavericks-ver-10.9.4

Thanks.

Comment: `Code | Inspect Code...` ??

Comment: Thanks LazyOne. Code | Inspect Code... is the solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the top menu and select "Code". In there select "Inspect Code". You will be able to select a scope and then PhpStorm will issue a report of what you want (as well as other things).